# Walk navigation panning controls?

Tags: 3d-view, navigation

I  have a PS4 gamepad that I am mapping to the controls for the Blender walk navigation to control my camera. This is basically very similar to what is happening in this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7qgY5ZvA6ZY).

I successfully managed to map the W, A, S, D, E, and Q keys. I also tried mapping the movement of the mouse to control how the camera pans. Attaching a screenshot of the options I have on the app I'm using to map the keys below (Gamepad Mapper, OS Ventura). I have experimented with both Mouse Cursor and Mouse Scroll, and although the actual cursors moves outside Blender, the view does not follow it in Walk Navigation.

Does anyone know what Blender would consider the right mouse/key combination to pan the camera? or have any other ideas?

I suppose I could always use Fly Navigation instead, but the movement doesn't feel as natural to me.

[image]